# How to run an app that require Java SDK on macOS Catalina 10.15?

Tags: java, catalina

Currently I am getting issue with new macOS Catalina limitation. Every time I run an app that require openJDK I get this message:

> "openjdk-12.0.1.jdk" can’t be opened because it is from an unidentified developer.
>
> Your security preferences allow installation of only apps from the App Store and identified developers.

But if I use the recommended way to bypass this issue (by going to System Preferences → Security & Privacy → General → Open Anyway button) it just opens the JDK folder. Which is not what I want.

How I can use JDK with macOS Catalina?

Comment: Could it be an issue with notarization? Did you try to notarize your app?

Answer (score 16):

Open `System Preferences` -> `Security & Privacy` -> `General`, there should be a message about the JDK app, click `Allow`.

Run the Java-based app again (e.g.: type `java -version` in the Terminal app). A dialog should appear confirming you trust OpenJDK.

Source: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/372235/35845

Answer (score 12):

A solution, not sure if that's the only solution & the better one, is to run

```
sudo spctl --master-disable
```

Then run your app (validation will be kept by macOS Gatekeeper)

and right after that re-enable Gatekeeper with

```
sudo spctl --master-enable
```

This last step is important to keep you Mac safe :)

Comment: Well, disabling system protection is never going to be a good option, but I can't see another way around for now. Hopefully OpenJDK will be updated soon enough to resolve this issue.

Comment: For me this is the only thing that worked. The allow message never enabled the java command to work, nor did spctl -add

Answer (score 5):

After testing different options, pinning to the latest LTS cask worked for me.  (edit: you will need to add the tap to show previous cask versions)

```
brew tap homebrew/cask-versions
brew cask install java11
```

Here's the output I get afterwards on Catalina Public Beta 2

```
java -version
openjdk version "11.0.2" 2019-01-15
OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9, mixed mode)
```

Comment: ℹ️This doesn't work for `brew cask install java6`

Comment: @Mikeumus the post clearly states "pinning to the latest LTS cask worked"; java6 is not the latest LTS, java11 is.  please consider removing a downvote as a help to others.  disabling gatekeeper is not a great option.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't downvote Chad https://imgur.com/a/8maWkjP
I left this note here for people looking to get java6 working and winding up here. I have my own Q/A for java6 here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/370141/brew-cask-install-java6-cannot-install-on-volume-because-it-is-disabled-ma/370168#370168

Comment: There, have an upvote!  3️⃣

Comment: gotcha thanks for clarifying; def not fishing for upvotes; merely hoping to avoid having people disable security on their Macs, that the other popular answer is advocating for.

Comment: Java 6 is 32-bit.  32-bit apps do not work on Catalina.  Your best bet is to update to a Java a bit more modern than that (8 at the minimum, 11 or 12 preferred)

Answer (score 1):

I tried master-disable but the problem reoccured after a reboot. In my particular situation, brew isn't what I want either.

Only solution I've found that works for me is

```
xattr -d com.apple.quarantine /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk1.8.0<version>/
```

Answer (score 0):

Detail steps to solve such problem on macOSX Catalina (or macOS-XI/11/X1 Big-Sur) is shown here https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/396025/133434

Summary:
• Download Java (JDK/SDK) version `*.tar.gz` file that you need for macOS from [OpenJDK](https://jdk.java.net/archive/) site into default `"~/Downloads"` folder, & verify its authenticity by comparing the OpenJDK site's shown SHA256 digest code, with the locally computed SHA256 digest code.
• Double-click on `*.tar.gz` to decompress it, & with a privileged user access+Password allow macOS to decompress it, (you will need allow decompress from here: `"System Preferences"` > `"Security & Privacy"` > under `"General"` tab > Goto bottomside section `"Allow Apps Downloaded From"` > press the "Allow" or "Open anyway" button).
• Move the decompressed new `jdk*.jdk` folder into `"/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/"` folder
& with a privileged user access+Password allow macOS to complete the move.
• In Terminal, run: `$($(/usr/libexec/java_home --version 12.0)/bin/java -version)`
& again specify a privileged user access+Password, to allow macOS "Open"/run it.
• From that point-on, that `java` should work fine.
• before running a java based App, either setup the JAVA_HOME env var globally (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135688/)) , or Use a shell-script: to select a specific Java version/folder before starting a specific java-based App.

if you're using Java 14, then change version number in above command, into `--version 14.0`
you can see all installed Java versions with: `/usr/libexec/java_home -V`

and avoiding `brew`/Homebrew(pkg-mngr) based solution would be better choice<sup>[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homebrew_%28package_manager%29#Data_collection), [2](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=11566720), [3](https://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/4gj664/homebrew_enabled_tracking_with_google_analytics/), [4](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/191364/), [5](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/105088/), [6](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/197095/), ...</sup>, users may use Macports(pkg-mngr), etc.

Answer (score 0):

this is one of the helpful workarounds that worked for me rather than compromising with security.

Open System Preferences -> Security & Privacy -> General, there should be a message about the JDK app, click Allow.