# Can't run OpenJDK macOS Catalina "Can't verify it's not a Virus"

Tags: macos, install, java, catalina

I downloaded OpenJDK 13 from the official website and extracted it to my `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/` folder. If I now try to run it with `java -version` I get a prompt saying something around the lines of "macOS can't verify it is not a Virus" and asks me if I want to delete it or cancel.

- The Tar's Checksum matches the one from the Website.
- I used `sudo` in order to move the folder, otherwise I got access denied
- Running java as `sudo` changes nothing

Any ideas on how I can get OpenJDK 13 to install on MacOS Catalina?

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :)  I hope you come to find this site has a lot to offer! In case you haven't already, it's worth taking the time to read the [tour](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour). All the best with getting OpenJDK 13 installed.

Comment: Please check the exact wording of messages. It's much more likely to say something like "MacOS cannot verify the identity of this software" than "MacOS can't verify it is not a virus". There is a world of difference.

Comment: @benwiggy the subtext sad "macOS kann nicht verifizieren, dass diese App keine Malware enthält." which translates into that, but you are right, the main text was "MacOS cannot verify the identity of this software"

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Go to `System Settings` -> `Security & Privacy` -> `General` -> click 'Allow' (below 'App-Downloads allowed from')

After that open a terminal and run java again (e.g. `java -version`).
A new Dialog should appear with the possibility to trust OpenJDK futurewise.

Comment: I already have this setting like this but it didn't fix it for me - but I dont have the exact same error as in the question, I have the error, `“jdk-14.0.1.jdk” is damaged and can’t be opened.` so maybe that is different.

Answer (score 22):

The issue is that macOS labels all downloaded binaries with a “quarantine” attribute which tells the system that it should not be run automatically before being explicitly approved by the user.

You have to manually remove the quarantine attributes from the folder where it’s been downloaded. You can do this easily in the terminal with this command:

```
xattr -d com.apple.quarantine /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-13.0.1.jdk
```

*Note: I don't own this solution/answer, here is the reference [blog](https://errors.wtf/openjdk-cannot-be-opened-because-the-developer-cannot-be-verified-adb-brew/). I am putting it here so that someone can find the answer easily.*

Comment: 1,000,000 internet points to you, @Nikhil Pate. This was the answer I needed.

Comment: this is the correct answer for the newst version of macOS

Comment: Just to reinforce that this is the correct answer for Big Sur

Comment: This should be the accepted answer because allowing the app in System Setting -> Security & Privacy no longer works in Mac OS Big Sur.

Comment: This worked for me on OS X Catalina.

Answer (score 9):

For those who miss rejected the JDK execution (the confirmation dialog will not let you choose to open again) and there is no "allow" button found in the Security dialog, you will need the command-line tool `spctl`:

```
# verify if you have rejected the app:
spctl --assess /path/to/jdk
# add app exception:
spctl --add /path/to/jdk
```

For those who just want to use the java executables in the command line, go to:

`System Preference > Security & Privacy > Privacy > Developer Tools`

Add `Terminal`, `iTerm2` or whatever applications you'd like to use

[image]

Comment: when I run, `spctl --assess /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-14.0.1.jdk/` I get the message, `a sealed resource is missing or invalid`

Comment: google point me [here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/105899), so my wild guess is broken files?

Comment: thank you @clarkttfu - the post suggests that I have french characters in the name - but as you can see from my example this doesn't apply in my case.

Comment: I did not mean you are facing the exactly same issue, but the issue should be somehow related to signature check. I guess the JDK files on your disk have been broken. You might need to download/extract those files and try again..

Comment: I have already tried this last week and you're right it works - but I dont want to do this everytime.... when I extract the JDK I then install the JMC-7 package into the Contents/Home directory of the JDK I wonder if this could be having an affect.

Comment: I have no experience with Apple code signature. But from your description, my guess is that by adding the package, you are probably breaking the JDK integrity -- may be some files were deleted or replaced in the process?

Comment: yes that would make sense - I am not deleting or replacing any files - just unpacking the tar into the /Contents/Home directory but I can imagine that Apple notices this change and so thinks that maybe there is some funny stuff going on and tries to protect me - question is how to get around this issue.. I have logged a separate issue for this here, `https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/393926/jdk-14-0-1-jdk-is-damaged-and-can-t-be-opened`

Comment: @robbie70 that sounds like an issue with the java install and might get a better response asking the authors of jmc or on a java mailing list.

Comment: @user151019 ok thank you - thats a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

[OpenJDK](https://openjdk.java.net/) Java (includes JRE) is open-source, & it is FREE for any Commercial & any deployment/distribution & any Personal usage.
[Oracle Java (JDK)](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-downloads.html) (includes JRE) has OpenJDK & closed-source/proprietary components, & it is free only-for Personal usage, a paid License required for any Commercial usage & for any deployment/distribution, & all users also must do a (free) web-registration to download any binary/source. You may see [this](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/9021/) too.

- in macOS-X Catalina (or macOS-XI/11/X1 after it), obtain the `"openjdk*.tar.gz"` archive-file (not dmg/zip) from `OpenJDK.Java.net` or its [archive](https://jdk.java.net/archive/)-page, (make sure you see "http**s**" (or Locked-Lock-symbol) in web-browser when you download) . Then verify/compare downloaded file's authenticity/integrity : you may use hash/digest SHA256 code shown on openjdk site, Use `openssl` tool in Terminal utility : with such command: `openssl sha256`   & then drag the `openjdk*.tar.gz` file from Finder into that `openssl` command-line in Terminal, press enter to compute hash/digest, then Compare computed `SHA256` digest-code with `sha256` what is shown on `https://OpenJDK.Java.net/` secure webpage, both must match/same,
- double-click on `"openjdk*.tar.gz"` (to decompress it) in Finder , MacOS may show notice & stop that,
- Open your `"System-Preferences"` > `"Security & Privacy"` > under `"General"` tab > goto bottomside section `"Allow Apps Downloaded From"` > press the "Allow" or `"Open anyway"` button there to allow the decompression of `"openjdk*.tar.gz"` archive-file (macOS will ask to enter Password of a privileged Admin type account), then it should decompress , if it does not decompress then again double tap on the `"openjdk*.tar.gz"` file in Finder, & choose `"Open"`/"Allow" button if macOS asks you again , then it will finally decompress that `"*.tar.gz"` file, & extract a folder from it,
- copy that newly extracted/decompressed OpenJDK folder `"jdk*.jdk"` , & goto below destination folder & MOVE (to move use the "alt/option" button to change the "paste" mode into "move" mode) the `"jdk*.jdk"` folder inside below destination location:
  `"/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/"`
  macOS will ask again to enter a privileged accnt Password, do that to complete the move.
- open Terminal , run this command: `/usr/libexec/java_home`
  if output contains+shows : `"/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-*.jdk/Contents/Home"` , where `*` will actually show the Java version number, then its good.
- in Terminal, run this long command-set:
  `echo '#!/bin/bash' > ~/TestJava.sh ; echo "export JAVA_HOME=\"\$(/usr/libexec/java_home --version 14.0)\";" >> ~/TestJava.sh ; echo "export PATH=\"\$JAVA_HOME/bin:\$PATH\";" >> ~/TestJava.sh ; echo "java -version ;" >> ~/TestJava.sh ; chmod +x ~/TestJava.sh ; ~/TestJava.sh`
  if you want to avoid above long command-set, then run below shorter command:
  `$($(/usr/libexec/java_home --version 14.0)/bin/java -version)`
  macOS will ask you to enter a privileged accnt + Password again, do that, & choose `"Open"`/"Allow", then you should see output like this:
    `openjdk 14.0.1 2020-04-14`
    `OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 14.0.1+7)`
    `OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 14.0.1+7, mixed mode, sharing)`
  (at the time of writing this answer i used openjdk 14.0.1, so above output shows those . if you're using Java 13, & if you want to use long command-set shown above then run this `nano` command after that: `nano ~/TestJava.sh` , & change the line which has version number `14.0`, into `13.0` , if you want to use a shorter command which is also shown in above, then (also for this) just change the `14.0` into `13.0`)
- Done . From this point-on, you will-not/should-not see any-other blocks/locks from macOS for using/running that `java`.

OPTIONAL STEP : if you want-to & need-to, then before running a java-based App, either setup the `JAVA_HOME` env var globally (to apply same Java on all java-based apps), or Use a shell-script to setup a specific Java to run a specific java-based App . A sample of such shell script is already shown in above long command-set , suit/change/modify that to your needs . if you want-to then follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62874205/3553808)(goto bottom-side "Optional : Java ENV VAR" section) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135688/)(recommended) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30537995/) or any other better instructions.

OPTIONAL STEP : you can see all installed Java versions with: `/usr/libexec/java_home -V`
(you should see your installed version on the displayed list)

Comment: I think there is one remaining problem even after this detailed outline (thanks), namely that whatever installed java JDK/JRE will work fine ONLY AS LONG AS your java app exploits what is currently set as default system resource. Ex: If mic is currently not default, java can only access it if java is run from terminal. Then it is terminal asking for the mic resource. Java currently DOES NOT. which is a CRISIS. Either Apple must grasp that Java is surviving, or Oracle must learn MacOs MUCH BETTER.

Answer (score 1):

1. Install homebrew packet manager (https://brew.sh/)

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"
```

2. Install AdoptOpenJDK (https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/homebrew-openjdk):

```
brew install --cask adoptopenjdk
```

3. Done.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you have to go into Mac's Security settings and allow the JDK there after your ran it.

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens because it wasn’t registered by an installer, which is why you get the error when you extract a tarball into a system directory but not when you use the pkg. If you want to use an installer package but don’t have a paid oracle subscription for versions above 8 you may have some luck using the supported openjdk which has signed packages on adoptopenjdk’s site.